# Color manually the axis title (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, visualization

How can I color manually the y-axis title (using ggplot2).

The title and subtitle work but not the y-axis label.

```r
labs(title = "Cat food brands: <span style='color:#FF4500;'>**8 brands decreased in sale**</span>",
       subtitle = "YEAR-OVER-YEAR % CHANGE IN SALE VOLUME ($)<br>",
       y = "DECREASED | INCREASED")
```

Thank you very much !
[image: bar graph]

Comment: Have you looked into the ggtext package? https://rfortherestofus.com/2020/05/color-titles-ggtext/

Comment: Not to mention the `ggtext` package vignettes directly, see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggtext/vignettes/theme_elements.html and scroll down to just *above* the "Text boxes" section.